# Como obtener la hora de un TimeSelector omitiendo la fecha

Tags: asp.net

Asignar a un TextBox  UNICAMENTE la hora de un TimeSelector, lo estoy tratando de hacer de estas 3 maneras pero no lo consigo.

```
Dim Hora As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtTotalHoras.Text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)'opcion1
Dim Hora As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtTotalHoras.Text, "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)'opcion2
Dim Hora As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}:{1}", TimeSelector1.Hour, TimeSelector1.Minute))' opcion 3
txtTotalHoras.Text = Hora
```

Answer (score 0):

La manera de hacerlo es creando un objeto de tipo `DateTime` y dandole formato de la siguiente manera:

```
 Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2} {3}", TimeSelector1.Hour, TimeSelector1.Minute, TimeSelector1.Second, TimeSelector1.AmPm))
```

Luego simplemente se asigna al textBox el objeto creado `time` con la propiedad `ToLongTimeString`

```
TextBox1.Text = time.ToLongTimeString
```

Finalmente queda así el código:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2} {3}", TimeSelector1.Hour, TimeSelector1.Minute, TimeSelector1.Second, TimeSelector1.AmPm))
        TextBox1.Text = time.ToLongTimeString
    End Sub
```